# Visual studio 2017 Solution explorer project change icon

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to change "Class Library" or "Folder" Icon inside solution explorer ? I have seen many projects which had icons on "Folder" & "Class Library"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons for items shown in Solution Explorer are defined in their templates. So you can modify the Icon tag content in templates you need and then execute command 'devenv /installvstemplates' to refresh them.

That is a sample of template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">

  <TemplateData>

    <Name>Text File</Name>

    <Description>A blank text file.</Description>

    <Icon>Text.ico</Icon>

    <ProjectType>IronPython</ProjectType>

    <SortOrder>180</SortOrder>

    <DefaultName>TextFile.txt</DefaultName>

  </TemplateData>

  <TemplateContent>

    <ProjectItem>TextFile.txt</ProjectItem>

  </TemplateContent>

</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: It changes in specific project ? and where is location of vstemplate ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/upgrading-custom-project-and-item-templates-for-visual-studio-2017#template-scanning